# How would I Use Python to Create a Google Sheet Similarly to R's googlesheets4 Package?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to send a simple Pandas DataFrame to Google Sheets. It's way more complicated than I expected and I would appreciate some help.

Creating a Google Sheet in R is incredible simple - using the googlesheets4 package, I just have to run gs4_create('Sheet_Name', sheets = My_Data), sign in to my Drive account when it prompts me to, and Voila! the sheet is created.

I have extensively researched doing the same with Python. From everything I've gathered, I need to access the Google Developers Console, create a project, enable the API, create a service account, give that service account editor permission, generate credentials, store them on my machine, and then run a script that accesses my credentials, authorizes them, and then maybe if all that works I can create a Google Sheet. Given all of this can be accomplished in one line of R code, do you understand why I'm a little frustrated and confused?

Is there not a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.